# WindowsForm WebBroswer

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, webbrowser

Есть два WebBrowser в первый загружаю html структура

```
<ul>
 <a href"..."><li>1 пункт</li></a>
 <a href"..."><li>2 пункт</li></a>
 <a href"..."><li>3 пункт</li></a>
</ul>
```

И есть второй WebBrowser в котором при нажатии на пункт в первом WebBrowser должен отобразиться тот файл на который ведет ссылка пункта

Что то типо такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем вообще html и WebBrowser ?

Comment: Заказчик -_- вот так вот

Comment: Напоминает функционал Microsoft Compiled HTML Help, `*.chm` файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было проще некуда

```
 private: System::Void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs^  e) 
             {
                 webBrowser1->Document->Body->MouseDown += gcnew HtmlElementEventHandler(this, &Form1::Document_Click);
             }
    private: void Document_Click(System::Object ^ sender,System::Windows::Forms::HtmlElementEventArgs ^ e)
             {
                 label1->Text = webBrowser1->Document->GetElementFromPoint(e->ClientMousePosition)->GetAttribute("href");
                   //webBrowser1->Document->GetElementFromPoint(e->ClientMousePosition);
             }
```